# get the path of a resource in Java and get a path that can be opened in Browser with Special Characters

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I'm doing Selenium Tests and I want to open a Resource in Java Code like that :

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fileWith[]");
```

The file I have to open contains '[' and ']' in its filename. I can't change the name.

If I call

```
url.getPath();
```

I get some String with '%5b' and '%5d' which I can't open in the Browser.

Which Encoding do I have to do to open the path in the Browser on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charaters that you see is URLEncoded you have to decode the values and you should be fine. For testing purpose you could use [link](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/UrlEncode/Encode.aspx).

The reason why you are not able to open the file is because there is no file with that name (fileWithURLEncodedValues).